# TFS 2013 Create New Project , web view

Tags: tfs

Dears

I use TFS 2013 ,  Link "new team project" dose not appears , i use administrator account

1. I go to "TFS_IP/tfs/_Admin" .
2. Then select DefaultCollection .
3. Click manage cotillion security and group membership.
4. set create new project "Allow" .
5. in over view tab , all old projects will appears as a list but there is no  "new team project".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating team projects via the web portal was not an option until TFS 2015. For earlier versions, you must use Visual Studio.